# When mouse hover to third level, second level font color changed drop down menu css

Tags: css, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with the drop down menu style..

when I mouse hover the third level, the second level font color is changed to its color..

I want to make it keep white (as hover) when third level is hover..

How can I make it?

My style:

```
<style type="text/css">
/*---- CROSS BROWSER DROPDOWN MENU ----*/

ul#nav
{
    margin: 0 0 0 0px;
}

ul.drop a
{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    color: #006699; /*font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;*/
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.drop a:hover
{
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff; /*font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;*/
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.drop, ul.drop li, ul.drop ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; /*border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #555;*/
    color: #000000;
}

ul.drop
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 597;
    float: left;
}

ul.drop li
{
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    zoom: 1;
}

ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 599;
    cursor: default;
    background: #006699;
}

#heading:hover
{
    background: #E9E9EB;
}

ul.drop ul
{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 598;
    width: 150px;
    background: #E9E9EB;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

ul.drop ul li
{
    float: none;
}

ul.drop ul a
{
    color: #000000;
}

ul.drop ul ul
{
    top: -2px;
    left: 100%;
}

ul.drop li:hover > ul
{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

My code:

```
<ul id="nav" class="drop">
    <li id="heading">@Html.ActionLink("Diamonds", "", "", "", new { style = "width:90px; text-align:center; color:black" })
        <ul>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Diamond Search", "", "")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About Diamond", "", "")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Custom Your Diamond Jewellery", "", "")
                <ul>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Create Your Own Ring", "", "")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Create Your Own Earrings", "", "")</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Images:

Before third level hover:

[image: Before third level hover]

After third level hover:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a simple CSS issue.

```
ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 599;
    cursor: default;
    background: #006699;
    color: #fff; /* <----------- ADDED */
}

#heading:hover
{
    background: #E9E9EB;
    color: #000; /* <----------- ADDED */
}
```

Working [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/fSHEF/)

You may also want to adjsut this line:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Diamonds", "", "", "", new { style = "width:90px; text-align:center; color:black" })
```

to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Diamonds", "", "", "", new { style = "width:90px; text-align:center;" })
```

Comment: Works perfectly in FF 20.0.1 here.

Comment: Works just fine in FF here.

Comment: @Scott the second menu text doesnt turn black when hovering over the third menu in the jsfiddle

Comment: @Ozzy Uhm.. that was the error to fix. Please reread the question. The second level should **not** be black when hitting the third level. Unless I'm the one who totally misread the question.

Comment: @Scott Oh I'm sorry I thought the other way was required

Comment: @Scott: I've tried the code, but nothing happens.. It still same, changed to black.. ;(

Comment: @user1903766 Please see updated answer. If this still doesn't work, then you've got CSS or HTML somewhere else (which you haven't posted) causing the problem. As you can see in my demo, it works.

Comment: @Scott: I don't know where's the problem.. I also checked all my style.. It looks ok, but it still didn't works.. anyway, thanks for your answer.. ;)